# CD services: Logger times out during Odata initialisation

Tags: content-delivery

My 8.5 preview service is not starting correctly. When it tries to construct `services/odata-v4-framework/odata_service-2.3.4.jar!/com/sdl/odata/service/ODataServiceImpl.class` I see the following error.

> ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ODataServiceImpl'

Somewhat further down the logs, the cause appears to be a timeout from the logging system.

> Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Could not start logger due to [akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due to [akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]]]

Frankly though - I'm not sure if this is the root cause. If it helps, I can post the entire log, but most of it is more or less repeated stack traces.

Is this a known issue? Is there a way I can tell the logger not to time out so quickly? (It's a heavily loaded image - maybe a bit of extra time to start up is all it needs). What else can I try?

Edit - this also happens for my discovery service. I'm assuming that it can happen for any service that uses the same logging library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka configuration is built into a jar file of odata framework (odata_service-xx.jar).

Adding to answer from Nickoli Roussakov, the logger timeout can be set using JVM Options in the startup script of the failing service.

Try adding following in `start.ps1 ($jvmoptions)` or `start.sh (JVM_OPTIONS)`

```
-Dakka.logger-startup-timeout=30s
```

Comment: This appears to work. Thanks. I now have this setting on my discovery, content and preview services, and so far there aren't any TIMEOUT's in the logs.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a few others outside of the Tridion domain have experienced this issue. Here is an answer that hints on why this is happening and how to increase the timeout:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367550/1284894

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'd already seen this. Unfortunately there's no indication as to where that configuration might go in a Tridion system.